# How to disable postfix forwarding to non-local domains

Tags: postfix-mta

I have configured postfix with virtual accounts, and there are some forwardings defined via `virtual_alias_maps`. The problem is that I want to block all forwarding for domains not in `virtual_mailbox_domains`, so that the mail can be forwarded locally (withing the mail server), but won't  be forwarded outside the server (e.g. won't be forwarded to gmail.com).

Exerpt from main.cf:

```
mydestination = localhost, localhost.localdomain
inet_interfaces = all
message_size_limit = 30720000

virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-domains.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-aliases.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual-mailboxes.cf
```

Comment: Is this server the final destination for mail, or is this simply a mail relay?

Comment: It's the final destination. The idea is not to relay mail as it gets caught and flagged as spam.